# Is this paper's finding on radiation-pressure displaced Lagrange point $L_1$ incorrect?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, radiation-pressure

I'm referring to the paper *An L1 positioned dust cloud as an effective method of space-based geo-engineering* which can be found here: http://strathprints.strath.ac.uk/27439/. I am about to try writing to the authors to see if they have issued a correction or are aware of the error, but I wanted to confirm here first.

In this paper they begin by deriving the radiation-pressure adjusted first Lagrange (L1) point. In brief: at the L1 point between the Earth and Sun, the grav. force from the sun inward balances with the grav. force of the Earth outward to make an object at that point orbit the sun at the same rate as the Earth (or, analyzed in a rotating reference frame with the Earth, the inward Sun gravity plus the outward Earth gravity plus the apparent outward centrifugal frame-force balance to zero and the object remains stationary). When you add radiation pressure to the mix, that will add an extra little push outward, so the equilibrium position will have to shift sunward a bit to compensate. The authors go through some elegant dimensionless equation stuff to come up with an answer, but when I do my brute force numerical check I find something very different. Here's how I go about it:

The acceleration due to gravity from the sun is:

$$
a_{g,sun}=\frac{-G_0 M_{sun}}{d^2}
$$

where $G_0$ is positive and $d$ is the distance from the sun

The radiation acceleration is:

$$
a_{rad}=\beta \frac{G_0 M_{sun}}{d^2}
$$

where $\beta$ is a convenient term often used in the literature to describe the ratio of acceleration due to radiation over acceleration due to solar gravity. Since both gravity and light flux fall off as $r^{-2}$, $\beta$ is just a materials dependent parameter and doesn't change with position.

The acceleration due to Earth gravity is:
$$
a_{g,earth}=\frac{G_0 M_{earth}}{(d_{earth}-d)^2}
$$
where $d_{earth}$ is the distance of Earth from the sun.

Since I'll work in the rotating reference frame I will also consider the centrifugal acceleration:

$$
a_{cent}=\omega^2 d
$$

where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the rotating frame ($\sim 2 \pi$ radians per year).

The sum of these accelerations should be 0 at the adjusted equilibrium point:

$$
a_{net}=(\beta-1)\frac{G_0 M_{sun}}{d^2}+\frac{G_0 M{earth}}{(d_{earth}-d)^2}+\omega^2 d=0
$$

Solving for $d$ is not straight forward, but Mathematica makes light work of it, and I find that when I plug in values and try different $\beta$ parameters I get vastly different results than the authors. For instance, at $\beta=0.772$ I find an equilibrium position at 0.61 AU. This is 5.7e7 km sunward of the classic L1 point. In their paper (second paragraph of section 4.2), they state that for a $\beta$ value of 0.772 the L1 point will be displaced sunward by only 9.5e5 km. That's a 60x difference!

Can any cooler heads confirm my math? If so, do you know what the authors did wrong?

I suspect it has something to do with the reduced mass parameter, $\mu=M2/(M1+M2)$, that they use in their dimensionless work. They adjust it with the beta parameter, $\mu=\frac{M2}{(1-\beta)(M1+M2)}$, but I wonder if by doing this they've altered the Earth's position to assume it also has a significant Beta value.

Comment: In its current form, this looks like a "check my work" question, which is off-topic. Please try to organise it to focus on the concept you're not sure about.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that what they're doing with beta & the reduced mass seems a bit weird.